# How to remove margin-left and margin-right of col class in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to bootstrap. I put 3 images side by side but they are not adjacent. There is a margin between them. [This is picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODYmS.png)

I want to eliminate the margins so that the images are adjacent. The center image size is 1200x400 and both left and right images size is 600x400. And also I've used `img-responsive` class. what is the actual problem?
Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/right.jpeg" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/center1.jpg" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/right.jpeg" runat="server" />    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you notice in picture, these pictures are not vertically aligned properly how to fix it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yorki Bonilla said you can do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row no-marginLR">
    <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
        <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/right.jpeg" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">
        <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/center1.jpg" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
        <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/right.jpeg" runat="server" />    
    </div>
</div>
```

And add a class in your CSS

```
.no-padding {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

But at the same time you have to remember to remove the left and right margin to the row that contains your columns by doing:

```
.no-marginLR {
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Note that I've added the .no-marginLR class to the row

Comment: This is not working. Hence, the margin for .r has to be reduced to 0.

Answer (score 4):

With Bootstrap v4 you can use:

```
<div class="row no-gutters"></div>
```

this will set margin-left and margin-right to 0

Bootstrap class:

```
.no-gutters {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<row class='no-gutters'>...</row>`

I realize you've tagged your question with version 3, however, Bootstrap 4 includes a class of `no-gutters` for grids. Eliminates the padding from the columns that you're seeing. that you're seeing (as well as the negative margin on the row).

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#no-gutters

As an example, 1 container with a standard row. And the same container with a row with the no-gutters class.

It's worth mentioning that when you're working within a framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, etc.) and you have a need for something simple like this, check the documentation.  Most likely it's been thought of and built in.  Oh and run from anyone telling you to put `!important` rules in your CSS.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
           <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="//fillmurray.com/300/300" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css class add `margin: 0 !important`;
this will remove all margins.
If you want to remove just left and right margins and keep top and bottom you need to specify `margin-left: 0 !important; margin-right: !important;`

Comment: Can you show the css code? Also check if it is padding from that css class.

Answer (score 0):

this is css code

```
body {
    background-color: #D8BFD8;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: #4c1f36;
  border-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #dddddd;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #4c1f36;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu > li.divider {
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #dddddd;
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #63304a;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #dddddd;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #eeeeee;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: #63304a;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #dddddd;
    background-color: #63304a;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .horizontal-menu {
        width: 700px;
        float: left;
        opacity: 0.95;    
    }

    .left {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}

.row-with-full-width {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood your question, here is the correct answer:

If you want the images to look like this:

[Corrected images next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Qab.png)

instead of like this:

[old images using your code for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb01a.png)

You need to delete the padding from the Col-sm that bootstrap has.

how?

Is not a good practice to delete the padding from the entire col-sm class.. so i would rather create a class for this particular case named (I dont know) "no-padding". and do this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
        <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/right.jpeg" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">
        <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/center1.jpg" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 no-padding">
        <asp:Image CssClass="img-responsive" ImageUrl="images/right.jpeg" runat="server" />    
    </div>
</div>
```

And now in your CSS:

```
no-padding {
padding: 0px;
}
```

**That should fix the images from having spaces between them.**