# Bootstrap 4 margin wont go to 0. I am using just css font and js

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am laying out the grid for a webpage I am developing. The problem is that I want the .container class, which has of my div to have 0 margin. I can get it to work if I use margin-left 0px; and there is no margin on that side. If I use margin-right: 0px; then there is no margin on the right side. I can't get it to work on both side for some reason. I do notice that when your in cell phone view. There are no margins at all.

The container class:

```
<div class="container con">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm grey">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-sm gr">column 2</div>
    <div class="col-sm grey padded">column 3</div>
  </div>
```

The styling that is being done for now on the same html page:

```
<style>

  .con{
    background-color: #a1a1a1;
    height: 200vh;
    width: 100%;



  }
  .grey{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 200px;

  }

  .gr{
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;

  }

.space{
    padding: 10px;

}

</style>
```

Does anyone have an idea that would eliminate the margin on both sides?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove margin-left and margin-right of col class in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328990/how-to-remove-margin-left-and-margin-right-of-col-class-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Container-fluid` or `m-0` class for your container to set the margin to zero.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the class `mx-0` of bootstrap to eliminate the margin. Here the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)

Answer (score 0):

```
mt-0 // Margin  Top 0
mb-0 // Margin Bottom 0
ml-0 // Margin  Left 0
mr-0 // Margin  Right 0

mx- 0 // Margin 0 in the horizontal ( left and right )
```

my- 0 // Margin 0 in the vertical ( top and bottom )